# After installing Ubuntu on external drive, my machine boots to grub instead of windows

Tags: grub2

I installed Ubuntu on an external drive, but I think it messed with my local boot record as it boots up an empty grub shell instead of the windows menu, even when the external isn't plugged in. Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: Boot windows recovery console and fdisk /fixmbr or similar.  Depends on what resources you have available to use.  You need a grub partition on your windows box to dual boot a fully persistent thumbdrive or grub installed on the thumbdrive itself, not on your /dev/sda-physical harddrive

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? If UEFI, you can just go into UEFI boot menu and select Windows. But if BIOS, you need the Windows fixed posted above. Do you want to be able to boot external on any other system? If so you  have to install boot loader on external drive. And big difference if UEFI or BIOS on external drive.

Comment: Thanks guys! I forgot to mention it was UEFI. I'm able to get into windows by going to the boot menu, but its annoying to always have to hold down the f12 key, especially as it boots pretty quickly and its easy to miss. How can I remove grub from my windows machine and install the boot loader on the external?